# My app was working fine but when I restarted android studio it threw this error message

Tags: android, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\rimsh\AndroidStudioProjects\fyp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not set unknown property 'plugins' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I deleted caches androidstudio>file>invalidate caches>restart
but it didn't work

Comment: Your question should show the code (a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)) that doesn't work the way you expect. Without that, it's highly unlikely that you'll get good feedback on what's wrong and how to fix it. It looks like there is a problem with your project build.gradle on line 25, so that's what we need to see.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android/app/build.grade and find

android {
compileSdkVersion X

The change the compileSdkVersion(X) to maximum compileSdkVersion!